# Read user directory in HTML 5 and load images in it

Tags: html, google-chrome, filesystems

I've been toying around with the FileSystem and File API, in Chrome, to try to implement a transient "instant gallery". The user chooses a directory, and all the images in it are then displayed in the webpage.

But I'm having a hard time, it seems Chrome requires some extra launching arguments to allow file access, FileSystem and File API are not W3C and not portable, I cannot instantiate certain objects...
I cannot even get the directory absolute path to open files in it (though maybe I don't need the absolute path, but I feel like it lacks a good documentation).

Anyway, I wanted to know how to implement this? Is there another API? A simpler way? Do I absolutely need to use FileSystem and File, and set Chrome's arguments?

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the files in the directory you will need to create a DirectoryReader object, and use the readEntries() method to read the content of the directory:

```
fs.root.getDirectory('Documents', {}, function(dirEntry){<br>
  var dirReader = dirEntry.createReader();
  dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {<br>
    for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
      var entry = entries[i];
      if (entry.isDirectory){
        console.log('Directory: ' + entry.fullPath);
      }
      else if (entry.isFile){
        console.log('File: ' + entry.fullPath);
      }
    }

  }, errorHandler);
}, errorHandler);
```

Please take a look here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/toying-with-the-html5-filesystem-api--net-24719

But I think that Chrome will not be able to access an entire directory that the user has selected from his computer, only if the user has selected multiple files in an input field. If that is ok and suits your needs there is a good tutorial here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Yep, I've been using all those already. And I ended up with the problem(s) I've exposed.